# Running a word VBA macro on text within two words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that converts track changes to either underline or strikethrough and it does it on the entire word document.  However, I would like it to run only on track changes only within a section of the document found between a first tag and a second tag (let's say between the words "Beginning" and "Ending").  I do not want this macro to make changes anywhere other than between these two tags. In other words, if I run this macro, only track changes within these two tags should be modified based on the macro and the rest of the document should keep its track changes intact.

Please let me know if you can help me modify this macro based on the above requirement.

Here's what I have but it runs on the entire document.

```
Sub FormatRevisions()
Dim rev As Revision, txt As String, r As Long, ran As Range

'First switch off TrackChanges, else each of your reformattings will become a revision again
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

'***Now cycle through revisions, identify type of change
For Each rev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
    Select Case rev.Type
        Case wdRevisionDelete
            'secure "deleted" text as well as its position
            txt = rev.Range.Text
            r = rev.Range.Start
            'accept the revision to make the markup disappear
            rev.Accept
            'now type the text formatted as strikethrough at the position of the old text
            Set ran = ActiveDocument.Range(r, r)
            With ran
                .Text = txt
                .Font.StrikeThrough = 1
            End With
        Case wdRevisionInsert
            Set ran = rev.Range
            'accept the revision to make the markup disappear
            rev.Accept
            'now type the text formatted as underlined at the position of the old text
            ran.Font.Underline = 1
    End Select
Next rev
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub FormatRevisions()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rvn As Revision, Rng As Range
'First switch off TrackChanges, else each of your reformattings will become a revision again
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  'Find the defined range
  With .Find
    .Text = "Beginning*Ending"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then

    '***Now cycle through revisions, identify type of change
    For Each Rvn In .Revisions
      With Rvn
        Select Case .Type
          Case wdRevisionDelete
            Set Rng = .Range
            'Reject the revision to make the markup disappear
            .Reject
            'now format the text as strikethrough
            Rng.Font.StrikeThrough = True
          Case wdRevisionInsert
            Set Rng = .Range
            'Accept the revision to make the markup disappear
            .Accept
            'now format the text as underlined
            Rng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        End Select
      End With
    Next
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above approach also has the advantage of retaining the formatting of the deleted and added text.